# Java Integer class and compareTo()

Tags: java

This code throws a null pointer exception at line 20, where the compareTo() is called. Any advice on how to get it to work?

```
package exam1review;

import java.util.Random;

public class ArrayTester {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int result, max=0;

    Integer[] myArray = new Integer[10];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        myArray[i] = rand.nextInt();
        System.out.println(myArray[i]);
        while (i != myArray.length - 1) {
            result = myArray[i].compareTo(myArray[i+1]);
            if (result > 0)
                max = myArray[i];
            else
                max = myArray[i+1];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(max);
}
```

}

Comment: Is there a reason for using `Integer` instead of `int`?

Comment: also, `i` never changes inside the while loop so it's bound to be infinite.

Comment: Why do you find the maximum value this way ? It's too complicated for such a simple task...

Comment: the while loop is unuseful in my opinion, is already included in for loop

Comment: There are very basic errors in the code. The same variable is used in both the for and while loop. The while loop doesn't increment/decrement the counter variable  which will cause to loop infinitely even if the error is not there. The reason for null pointer exception is accessing the array index which has not been initialized. You are accessing myArray[i+1] before it has a value assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you're looping over `i`, but your comparison tries to compare to `myArray[i+1]` before it's set.

Populate the array first, then look for the max value.

Like this:

```
package cruft;

import java.util.Random;

public class ArrayTester {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer[] myArray = new Integer[10];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            myArray[i] = rand.nextInt();
        }        
        for (Integer value : myArray) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("max value: %d", findMax(myArray)));
    }

    public static int findMax(Integer [] values) {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        if (values != null) {
            for (Integer value : values) {
                if (value.compareTo(max) >= 1) {
                    max = value;
                }
            }
        }

        return max;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Ya'll are right; simple errors, I guess I've been awake too long.

Answer (score 2):

Three issues:

1. You are trying to access `myArray[i+1]` while you only initialize it
   on next iteration of your `for` loop, **this is causeing you the NPE.**
2. Your condition is `(i != myArray.length - 1)` and later you access
   `myArray[i+1]`, which is out of bound for `i == myArray.length -
   1`.
3. The `while` loop: `while (i != myArray.length - 1)` from first galnce, it seems it will never be terminated, since you do not increase `i` in it.

Answer (score 2):

At the point where you execute

```
result = myArray[i].compareTo(myArray[i+1]);
```

the array element `myArray[i+1]` has not yet been set to anything.  Its value is null.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize myArray with non null values.

Answer (score 1):

The `Integer[]` array is initialized with 10 `null` values. You need to set them to actual numbers, or better - use `int[]` instead.

If you want to keep your logic, you'd need two loops - one to fill the array, and another to look for the maximum value.